# what happens when you run pkill ""

Tags: 18.04

I am trying to understand what happened, while working on my machine I noticed a crashed app with a

> " " is not responding

force quit or wait message on it, it had this icon and was named image on the title bar and "" in the error message [crashed app icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2DfR.png), I pressed force quit on the GUI and my mouse stopped clicking for a while. I then wanted to kill it through the terminal so I ran

```
pkill ""
```

but my screen went black and I found myself back into login screen, after I signed in the screen went black again, after I restarted my device everything was fine.

but what exactly happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pkill` (and `pgrep`) patterns use *Extended Regular Expression* (ERE) syntax. In ERE, the empty pattern "" matches any string. This is not the same as pattern " ", which only matches strings that contain the space character.

So your command `pkill ""` would have attempted to kill every process in your session.